# ng-repeat when data is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a website with two webpages:

1. A settings page: webpage with JSON content that looks like this:

   {"Sources":["1","2","3","4"]}
2. A webpage that present all the known "sources" in the system. Just print them one after another.

When my application loading, I downloading the sources page, and save in on my scope at `$scope.Settings.Sources`.

My AngularJS code:

```
$scope.getSettings = function (ID, successCallback, failureCallback)
{
    $scope.ID = ID;

    $http.get("/sources?ID=" + ID).then(function (response)
    {
        if (response.status == 200)
        {
            $scope.Settings = response.data;
            successCallback();
        }
        else
        {
            failureCallback();
        }
    });
}

function getSettings_success()
{
    // Ready to update the ng-repeat NOW.
}

function getSettings_error()
{
    alert('Error');
}

$scope.getSettings(1, getSettings_success, getSettings_error);
```

Now, when i have the `$scope.Settings.Sources` ready, all I have to do is to print each soruce in specific HTML template. Because of that, I was thinking to use the ng-repeat for this task. Something like this:

```
<div ng-init="sources=$scope.Settings.Sources">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="source in sources">
            {{ source }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't working. This because when the page is loading, the `$scope.Settings.Sources` isn't ready yet. So, the ng-repeat must run after the "sources" page was downloaded.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [**`ng-init`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for such case, because data is coming by Ajax and you are assigning blank object to source. Cause doesn't responded yet. Rather I'd use `Settings.Sources` variable directly on your view.

**Markup**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="source in Settings.Sources">
            {{ source }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> **Side Note**: `$scope` variable's directly accessible inside angular directives, you don't need explictly specify `$scope`

Comment: This is working. Thank you. But I don't understand how this working? how the ng-repeat "knows" when there are data in "Setting.Sources"?

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever that has been taken care by angular digest system..whatever variable binded on the view inside angular directive, evaluates there value on each digest cycle(here after ajax completes, angular runs a digest cycle and update binding)